# create a nested object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

```
let list=[{key1,children[]},{key2,children[]},{key3,children[]}]
```

How to get an array like this with javascript?

```
list1=[{key1,children[{key2,children[{key3,children[]}]}]}
```

I tried like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i + 1]) {
    list[0].children.push(list[i + 1]);
  }
}
```

but its pushing all children into `list[0].children`

Comment: Both the input and output have syntax errors, please may you fix them?

Comment: *but its pushing all children into list[0].children* You don't change list[0].children inside your loop. It would be weird if it start pushing your data somewhere else..

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to process your original list in reverse order, something like this should do it:

```js
let list=[{"key":"key1", "children":[]},{"key":"key2", "children":[]},{"key":"key3", "children":[]}]

let result = list.reverse().reduce( (acc,x,i, e) => {
   if(i == list.length-1){
      acc.push(x);
   }
   else{
      e[i+1].children = [x]
   }
   return acc;
   
},[]);


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution to Jamiec answer.

When the data is transformed, it does not mutate `list`, since a `structuredClone` is created. I also reduced right-to-left, because when the `index` reaches `0`, we will just return `[item`]. We do need to set a non-`undefined` value for the reducer initialized value. The value `null` will work.

While the `index` is greater than `0`, push the `item` as a `child` to the left of it.

```js
const list = [
  { key: "key1", children: [] },
  { key: "key2", children: [] },
  { key: "key3", children: [] }
]

const transformed = structuredClone(list)
  .reduceRight((acc, item, index, ref) => {
    if (index === 0) return [item];
    ref[index - 1].children.push(item);
  }, null);

console.log(transformed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

@Jamiec, instead of reversing the list, you can change the indexing. Be careful, this still modifies the original `list` array!

```js
const list = [
  { key: "key1", children: [] },
  { key: "key2", children: [] },
  { key: "key3", children: [] }
]

let result = list.reduce((acc, x, i, e) => {
  if (i === 0) {
    acc.push(x);
  } else {
    e[i - 1].children = [x]
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `structuredClone()` at all costs since it's a slow way to clone objects unless you want object references preserved. Use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` rather on data acting as data, not as a functional object.
For your case if you want a copy of the data, just create your custom `clone()` function:

```js
const list = [
  { key: "key1", children: [] },
  { key: "key2", children: [] },
  { key: "key3", children: [] }
]

const clone = elem => ({key:elem.key, children:[...elem.children]});

const result = [];
let head = result[0] = clone(list[0]);
for(let i = 1; i < list.length; i++){
  head.children.push(head = clone(list[i]));
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

And a benchmark against `structuredClone()`: 33x faster:

```
Cycles: 600000 / Chrome/117
---------------------------------------------------------
Alexander     38/min   1.0x    40    40    38    41    45
Polywhirl   1251/min  32.9x  1308  1272  1289  1251  1266
---------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark
```

```html
<script benchmark="600000">

const list = [
  { key: "key1", children: [] },
  { key: "key2", children: [] },
  { key: "key3", children: [] }
]

// @benchmark Polywhirl

structuredClone(list)
  .reduceRight((acc, item, index, ref) => {
    if (index === 0) return [item];
    ref[index - 1].children.push(item);
  }, null);


// @benchmark Alexander

const clone = elem => ({key:elem.key, children:[...elem.children]});

const result = [];
let head = result[0] = clone(list[0]);
for(let i = 1; i < list.length; i++){
  head.children.push(head = clone(list[i]));
}
result;
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: @SrilathaDanalakota if my answer worked for you don't forget to accept it (the checkbox), thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers